# How to update a table in postgres datable

Tags: node.js

Am new to node js.
I have a table where i would want to update the table but do not know how it's done.
I want to update 2 table columns and put "NULL"
How do i do that in node js?
I can't seem to get my way around it

Comment: It’s not clear what specific issue you’re having, or how you’re accessing PG.

Comment: To be specific i need a way to update a column of my table, say 'columnA' and put "NULL"

Comment: It’s unclear what is preventing you from doing so, or what library you’re using to access PG. Most libraries have examples of how to modify data.

Comment: am using sequelize

Comment: Yes it has but not clear i tried going through but did not get what i needed or maybe i just did not understand

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. You're not providing much information other than "I can't do it". What's the *specific issue*? [Updating a model](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#simple-update-queries) is what you want; set the field(s) to `null` and call `update`.